# Animating elements on canvas in QML from python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qml

Here is the *main.py* script:

```
import sys, os, math
import numpy as np
import time
from PyQt5 import *

class Tab(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(600, 600, 600, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Tab Widget")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("../QML Files/Icons/Tab.png"))
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        tabWidget.addTab(Example01(), "Ex1")
        vbox.addWidget(tabWidget)
        self.setLayout(vbox) 

class GG(QObject):
    polygonsChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._polygons = []

    def modify_Polygons(self) -> None:
        for x in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            GG.set_dynamic_polygons(x, self)

    def get_polygons(self) -> None:
        return self._polygons

    def set_polygons(self, polygons):
        self._polygons = polygons
        self.polygonsChanged.emit()

    polygons = pyqtProperty(
        "QVariant", fget=get_polygons, fset=set_polygons,
        notify=polygonsChanged
    )

    def set_dynamic_polygons(i, p_gg) -> None:

        numpy_arrays = np.array(
            [[[100+i, 100], [150, 200], [50, 300]],
             [[50, 60], [160, 20], [400, 10]]]
        )

        def set_polygons(myArray) -> []:
            polygons = []
            for ps in myArray:
                polygon = []
                # print("ps = "); print(ps)
                for p in ps:
                    # print("p = "); print(p)
                    e = QPointF(*p)
                    polygon.append(e)
                polygons.append(polygon)
            return polygons

        p_gg.polygons = set_polygons(numpy_arrays)


class Example01(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gg = GG()
        GG.set_dynamic_polygons(0, self.gg)

        view = QQuickWidget()
        ROOT_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

        qml = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "QML Files", "Demo01.qml")
        view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml))

        view.rootContext().setContextProperty("gg", self.gg)
        

        view.setResizeMode(QQuickWidget.SizeRootObjectToView)
        vbox.addWidget(view)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabDialog = Tab()
    tabDialog.show()
    App.exec()
```

Next follows the *Demo01.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15


Rectangle {
    id: rect

        visible: true
        anchors.fill: parent

        LinearGradient {
                anchors.fill: parent
                //setting gradient at 45 degrees
                start: Qt.point(rect.width, 0)
                end: Qt.point(0, rect.height)
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#ee9d9d" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#950707" }
                }
            }
        Button{
            id: btn
            width: 100
            height: 30
            x: {parent.width - btn.width - 20}
            y: {parent.height - btn.height - 20}
            text: "Click Me"
            onClicked: gg.modify_Polygons()
        }

        Canvas {
            id: drawingCanvas
            anchors.fill: parent

            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d")
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(100%,70%,30%)"
                ctx.lineWidth = 5
                ctx.strokeStyle = "blue"
                //console.log(gg)
                for(var i in gg.polygons){
                    var polygon = gg.polygons[i]
                    ctx.beginPath()

                    for(var j in polygon){
                        var p = polygon[j]
                        if(j === 0)
                            ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y)
                        else
                            ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y)
                    }
                    ctx.closePath()
                    ctx.fill()
                    ctx.stroke()
                }

            }

        }

        /*Connections{
             target: gg
             function onpolygonsChanged(){ drawingCanvas.requestPaint()}
         }*/

    }
```

The two triangles when I start the program are shown very nice.
The trouble appears when I click the button.
I tried all sorts of variants to indent the *modify_Polygons()* function inside the GG class.
In every version I received the same error: **Property 'modify_Polygons' of object GG(0x103056bd0) is not a function** comming from the *Demo01.qml*  -> row 30.
I don't have any clue why this error appears because for me looks like a legitimate function.

What did I make wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the elements of the QMetaObject are accessible from QML like the qproperties, signals and slots, and the other elements of the class are not visible from QML. So one solution is to use the @pyqtSlot decor.

On the other hand you should not use time.sleep as it will block the main thread and consequently freeze the GUI. If you want to do periodic tasks then use a QTimer.

```
@pyqtSlot()
def modify_Polygons(self) -> None:
    for x in range(10):
        # time.sleep(1)
        GG.set_dynamic_polygons(x, self)
```

On the other hand, if you want to make animations (even if you only indicate it in the title of your post) then you must use QVariantAnimation:

```py
@pyqtSlot()
def modify_Polygons(self) -> None:
    animation = QVariantAnimation(self)
    animation.setStartValue(0)
    animation.setEndValue(10)
    animation.valueChanged.connect(
        lambda value: GG.set_dynamic_polygons(value, self)
    )
    animation.setDuration(10 * 1000)
    animation.start(QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations